# How to find a text/number in entire sheet of Excel and return a value

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can i find a particular cell value (in sheet 1) in an another entire sheet (sheet 2) if it exists or not? There are multiple number like this in the sheet 1, so i need a formula. Otherwise find option is working fine.

Comment: Are you describing `VLookup` or the `INDEX`+`MATCH` combo?

Comment: Would you please tell us more about your question? What does **"return a value"** 
 mean? Maybe you could share a sample with us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COUNTIF()` function to count the number of cells that meet a specific criteria. If the count is greater than or equal to 1, the value **exists**, otherwise it doesn't.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34